# Does R2-D2 have coin slots on its side?

Tags: star-wars, r2-d2

Why does R2D2 have coin slots and a coin return?

[image]

Comment: How do you know they are coin slots?

Comment: Presumably the same reason Qui-Gon uses [a ladies razor](http://i.crackedcdn.com/phpimages/quickfix/2/0/2/179202_v1.jpg) as a communicator: there are all sorts of crazy and random things used as parts of props.

Comment: It's actually CD slots. Luke gets really bored otherwise, sitting in that cramped little cockpit for hours and hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously, they're not actual coin slots or a coin return. Those are just easy to remember names used by builders for ease of reference.

They're "system diagnostic ports" and a "[polarity sink](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Polarity_sink)":

[image: Official schematic of R2-D2 listing the vertical column of "coin slots" as "system diagnostic ports" and the "coin return" as a "polarity sink"—part numbers 40 and 20, respectively.]
Source: [Scale Model News: Star Wars R2D2 - Lego Mega-Model Coming Soon](http://www.scalemodelnews.com/2012/03/star-wars-r2d2-lego-mega-model-coming.html)

[image: R3 Astromech Droid and R4 Astromech Droid schematics showing their identically designed "coin returns" similarly labeled as "polarity sinks".]
Source: [R3-series astromech droid - Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R3-series_astromech_droid)

Comment: ah cool, that explains that then, I am too building an R2D2 and have recently bought resin coin slots, and that was why I asked this question... it didn't seem to make sense that he needed coin slots :)

Comment: why does the R4 have fewer features than the R3. You would think it has more?